# NestJS/Elastic apm: agent does not record database query spans

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, elastic-apm

I'm using `elastic apm` to profiling my `NestJS` application and my apm agent is `elastic-apm-node`.
My ORM is `typeOrm` and my database is `Oracle`.

My problem is apm agent does not record database query spans and I can't see **database query spans** in kibana ui.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately oracle is not supported by elastic apm agent. you should wrap your `oracleQueryRunner` in order to start and end agent spans manually. put this code in your `main.ts` file:

```
import { OracleQueryRunner } from 'typeorm/driver/oracle/OracleQueryRunner';

const query = OracleQueryRunner.prototype.query;

OracleQueryRunner.prototype.query = async function (...args) {
  const span = apm.startSpan('query');
  if (span) {
    span.type = 'db';
    span.action = args[0];
  }
  const result = await query.bind(this)(...args);
  if (span) { span.end(); }
  return result;
};
```